# Node js upload file and resize after or before

Tags: node.js, express, multer

I use `Express` and `multer` for uploading a file (**only images**). But I want to resize the image before or after. I searched a lot, and I found a lot of packages. For example `multer-imager`(**it wants amazon s3**).

I only want to upload files to my disk. I tried resizing the image before uploading with `Canvas` on clientside, but `multer` sees an unmodified image(**I use `multer` limiter (1mb)**) and I get the error:

> the file is bigger than 1mb. Because multer see unmodified image.

Comment: how do you uploading the images ? mobile app or web app

Comment: Web application

Answer (score 0):

I had a same issue in my Ionic 3 mobile application. You can use **[croppr.js](https://jamesooi.design/Croppr.js/)** to crop the image before send to the server side. check this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51164403/how-to-get-the-croped-image-using-croppr-js)

Comment: This is not my answer:)but ty for your attention

Answer (score 0):

You can use multer-transform package